# Can a very lowered suspension cause cv joint to leak?

Tags: suspension, leak, cv-joint

Car is a civic vti 1999 currently at 160k miles and looking rusty underneath.  The suspension has been lowered so much it is a nightmare to ride over humps.

Just found that I have leaking cv joints.  Based on age, mileage etc could very well be just wear and tear, however I'm just wondering if low ride height could easily cause it to maybe brush\scrape against something and maybe have caused the leak?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CV joints are affected by alignment angles, the reason they have joints to begin with is they compensate for independent movement of each wheel. if you ride on a high surface on one side of the car and the other side is lower, then each CV joint will compensate for those angles, within reason.
If the vehicle in question is aggressively lowered then id say it could be a contributing factor to them leaking but maybe not the *smoking gun* so to speak.

CV boots are made of a rubber flexible material, usually the outside portion of the CV joint (the side closest to the tire is considered the outer, and the joint closest to the transmission is the inner). These deteriorate over time, either Dry rotting or developing pin hole leaks either from road hazards or simply time.

If you have mechanical aptitude and patience you could change just the boots if the CV joints are not making any weird "clunking" noise while turning. 
I'm an advocate for repairing parts instead of replacing. If you are not then buy a lifetime axle from autozone for $75 or so with your old one to trade in and monitor the axles over time.

Answer (score 0):

On most suspensions the CV joints tend to suffer the most deflection when there is no load ie the body of the car is jacked up and the wheel is left to hang.

When the suspension is fully loaded, then the driveshaft tends to be almost straight (easy to check if you are replacing springs to actually see what is going on).

So, to answer your question, no lowering the suspension did not cause the failure unless you have something coming into contact with the rubber CV cover -which you should correct if that is the case. The rubbers most likely failed due to age & wear.